# In the IDA xrefs window, can I filter by unique addresses? Or is there an alternative view providing that?

Tags: ida

Consider the following screenshot:

[image: xrefs dialog in IDA]

Here, the `r` and `p` Type entries appear in pairs. We have ten entries, but five pairs.

Is there a way to filter this list down to unique *Address* values, rather than having those duplicates shown for each respective *Type*?

Comment: I don't think filtering by type is a feature for the UI (absolutely doable with IDAPython), but you can click the 'Type' column label to sort by type

Comment: @mimak it's a fair point, but there doesn't seem to be a sorting hierarchy. And sorting by address currently is the best short I have at inspecting each xref. If I sort by another metric, I will go all over the place when navigating, usually.

Comment: if you're willing to idapython it as mimak said, it's significantly easer to sort them by their flag (`dr_R`) & type. i'm the maintainer of ida-minsc over at github.com/arizvisa/ida-minsc which exposes those types for refs and can easily sort/group/fit them to a ui thing (if cared). there's a future branch over at github.com/arizvisa/ida-minsc/tree/persistence-refactor which returns a ref as an int-compat tuple with the "access" bit being a `set` of "&rwx" to distinguish loads/stores from data refs and regular code refs (as it's an import, you'd prolly use `db.xref.up` or `func.up` in minsc).

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago thanks so much for chiming in. I came across `ida-minsc`, didn't give it a try yet, however. But the remark about this flag is very valuable!